# Using before_filter in application controller and except

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use a before_filter in the application controller.
This filter should be used for every controller except two actions in one controller.

How can I define this exception?

Thanks!

Comment: Longer explanation can be found on this other [SO post][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072786/except-not-working-in-before-filter-in-application-controller-routing-problem

Comment: Basically duplicate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367847/before-filter-syntax-when-you-want-to-except-controller-abc

Answer (score 6):

Use [skip_before_filter](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html#M000533).

Answer (score 0):

In application controller you can mention:

```
    before_filter :xxxx, :except => [:name_of_1st_method, :name_of_2nd_method]
```

Note: The names of these methods should be unique across all controllers.

skip_before_filter is a good solution, but if, say, you want to use a application controller method only to specific methods across all controllers then the suggested technique is useful. Example:

```
    before_filter :xxxx, :only => [:method_name_in_controller1, :method_name_in_controller2]
```

A word of caution: Again, make sure the method names are unique across all controllers.