# How to make a method appear before ALL of the controllers action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, helper

I have several controllers in my rails app (UserController, PostController, SessionController etc...)

before all of each action I want to pass a json object using [gon gem.](https://github.com/gazay/gon)

I have added this line of code into my application helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper

   ...

  def adding_gon
      gon.signed_in = signed_in?      
  end
end
```

I have also added the ApplicationHelper to be available to all controllers:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ApplicationHelper
end
```

**the problem is that now I need to go to each controller and write this line of code:**

```
before_filter :adding_gon
```

This is rather a duplication to write this line of code to each controller.

**Is there a way to make this method execute before ALL actions?**

Comment: just as a guess: couldn't you just add it to the application controller? (I assume your other controllers inherit from it)

Comment: for further information read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5072825/915039)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since controllers are usually inheriting from `ApplicationController`, you do not have to add the `before_filter` to every controller. Just add the line inside of your `ApplicationController`'s class definition and the filter gets executed in front of all you subcontroller's actions, except you're inheriting from some other controller.