# before_filter syntax when you want to "except" controller "abc"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails what is the before_filter syntax when you want to "except" controller "abc".

Example, in the application_controller if I want to say:

```
before_filter :login_required :except => ["-name of controller-"]
```

Background - Just wanted basic authentication across the whole app except the controller that actually handles getting a user authenticated....

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can put the following line in the controller where the `before_filter` should not be executed:

```
skip_before_filter :login_required
```

You can even specifiy the methods where the `before_filter` is ignored with `:only` and `:except` options:

```
skip_before_filter :login_required, :only => [:login]
```

An example [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters).

---

Edit: with Rails 4, `before_filter` is aliased with `before_action`, and `skip_before_filter` is also aliased with `skip_before_action`

Answer (score 14):

The  `before_filter` syntax is

```
before_filter :login_required, :except => ["-name of the action-"]
```

Have a look on [Rails API Doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the controller name, I'd recommend taking advantage of the fact that controllers inherit their filters from their parent. So what I'd recommend is something like this:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController
  # no filters here
end

# app/controllers/authenticated_controller.rb
class AuthenticatedController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :login_required
end

# app/controllers/some_other_controller.rb
class SomeOtherController < AuthenticatedController
  # inherits the before_filter from AuthenticatedController
  # use this for most of your other controllers
end

# app/controllers/unauthenticated_controller.rb
class UnauthenticatedController < ApplicationController
  # no filters, since this inherits directly from ApplicationController
  # use this for the controller that you don't want to check login on
end
```

This means controllers know whether they're supposed to check login, rather than having a (possibly brittle) list of names.

Comment: @Thrabbit Glad to help! I think you might also be able to do this with module inclusion if you don’t want to use inheritance, but I haven’t tried that.